# How can I display Low Values on outside of Donut Chart using Google Visualization?

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart, donut-chart

When i create google donut chart by using the following html code

```
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     50],
      ['Eat',      50],
      ['Commute',  5],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.63,
      enableInteractivity: false,
      chartArea: {left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5, width: "100%", height: "100%"},
      tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
      pieSliceBorderColor: "#FFBE33",


       slices: {
                        0: {
                            color: '#FFBE33',
                            textStyle: {bold: false, fontSize: 12, color: 'white'}
                        },
                        1: {
                            color: 'blue',
                            textStyle: {bold: false, fontSize: 12, color: 'white'}
                        },
                       2: {
                            color: 'black',
                            textStyle: {bold: false, fontSize: 12, color: 'white'}
                        }
                    }


    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

it produce the output like this:

[image: donut chart with <5 value]

when i give <5 value ,it does not shows percentage value on donut chart. But when i give  >5 value means it shows correctly.

[image: donut chart with >5 value]

how can i display the percentage value outside or inside the donut chart like this?

[image: Expected Donut chart]